# React render - cannot access array data due to timing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have a function that takes time fetching data. When render is returned the first time the data `this.state` is not available so, based on numerous other questions like this, I try to use a ternary and re-render once the data is ready. I use the callback version of setState:

```
 this.setState(prevState => ({ comments: [...prevState.comments, top100Resolved ] }))
```

When the data (an array) is returned with setState I cannot access it. The goal is to map over it and push it through a template, but I cannot even index into it. This is the render.

```
render(){
//true once there is some state
   let bool = this.state.comments.length

      return (
        <div className="data">
        {
            bool ? 
    //Want to render markup here
          this.state.commments.map(comment => {
     <div>comment</div>  //nothing happens
      })
           : <div>Not ready</div> 
        }

      </div>)
  }
```

First `Not Ready` will appear.
But even once the `bool` is true and I get back `[Array(0)]`, I cannot index into it. `[Array(0)][0]` produces `[]` which is an array of objects. `[Array(0)][0][0]` should be an object but is `undefined.` So the map function is impossible currently.

https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/375bzycv/282/

Comment: why does that function takes time ? does it do anything asynchronously like fetching something over internet ?

Comment: @kumarmo2 Updated to inform that it is for a fetch.

Comment: try changing the type of comments to an empty array like this. comment: []

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you're mapping your IDs to promises is incorrect. All you're doing is your setting up a promise, but not waiting for it to finish, for every single ID. Instead, use `Promise.all` and get rid of the entire promise mapping stage:

```
Promise.all(top100Promises.map(id => {
  return this.getStory(id).then(obj => {
    if(obj) {
      if(obj.type === 'comment') {
        return obj
      }
    }
}))
  .then(comments => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      comments: [...prevState.comments, ...comments.filter(o => o)] // this filter removes non-comments that are undefined 
    }))
  })
```

This will wait for every comment to come in before setting state instead of setting state before any have come in. You can also shorten your `top100Promises` code to just:

```
let top100Promises = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => maxNum - i)
```

See [the updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8cLemrd/).